# Failed To download the chrome driver in windows server

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello guys i am getting an error when i tried to initialize the selenium chrome driver using asp.net in windows server.
The error is -

```
The file C:\Users\wealthclock\Desktop\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

can you guys please guide me what should i do here?
Thank you!

This is my code--

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", fullpath);
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("no-startup-window", "true");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--silent");
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\wealthclock\Desktop\",chromeOptions);
```

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: does the driver actually exists at that path?

Comment: ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", fullpath);
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("no-startup-window", "true");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--silent");
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\wealthclock\Desktop\",chromeOptions);

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there, please.

Comment: Have you tried putting the driver in any other path? or does it actually exist? what is fullpath here `chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", fullpath);`

Comment: I have tried with two ways.
one i put the driver.exe in my solution folder(without specify the path).
another one i mentioned the driver path in the code(where driver exist in the desktop of the PC.)
but i am getting the same error!

Comment: Is this failing locally or once you have pushed to a server?

Comment: No.In locally it's working fine.
i am getting the error in server!

Comment: I found a possible duplicate. Here is the Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548795/setup-chrome-webdriver-with-remote-chromedriver-exe-file?rq=1

Comment: @Niladri the full path is the default download location here..

Comment: I have tried with this also
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver", @"C:\\chromedriver.exe");
but same error!

Comment: @AbhirupGhosh does this path exists in server "C:\Users\wealthclock\Desktop\" along with the driver?

Comment: Yes.I placed the driver in the desktop

The file C:\Users\wealthclock\Desktop\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

this is the error i am getting!